# How can I disable both the boot splash and messages during boot?

Tags: 14.04, boot, plymouth

Any answers which I have read so far on how to disable the boot splash work by enabling text messages.

However I'd like to have a *completely black screen until the login screen*. Is it possible to disable both the boot splash and messages during boot?

Comment: Uncomment this line `#GRUB_TERMINAL=console` then run `sudo update-grub`

Comment: @KasiyA Thanks, but this does not seem to alter the boot. I still see either the boot splash or the messages.

Answer (score 2):

Edit `/etc/default/grub` using your favourite editor (`sudo nano` or `gksudo gedit`) and change

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
```

Then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

If `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` is set, you might have to remove `splash` there as well.

Comment: Thanks. I have set the following: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` and I did run `sudo update-grub`. But the text messages are still there.

Comment: @king_julien `quiet` suppresses a lot of output, but not all. You can try redirecting the output to another TTY: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=tty12"`.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint again, but this doesn't work for me :(

Comment: Can you show some example of what output you do get?

Comment: I made a video of the boot sequence: https://www.dropbox.com/s/iq4009pu6zuiy5j/askubuntu.com_q_529244_172081.mp4?dl=0 And here's a copy of `/etc/default/grub` http://pastebin.com/r6A3TTG3